Unable to subscribe to the presence channel on socket.io. Keeps erroring out
I'm using Laravel Echo and Socket.io@2.4 clients in a React Native project. When I use my dev server everything works fine, but when I switch to my server's production (a copy from Dev) I can connect but I start getting a 404 error when I try to subscribe to a private channel.  Any clues? Both images use the same host. It's been blocked out for security reasons, thanks for understanding.
Production server results
Dev server results
We tried looking at the commit history of our yaml files, explored CORS, asked other developers, tried debug mode, enabled Laravel Telescope, none of which worked.
We were expecting to find clues within the error logs as to why we werent able to subscribe to sockets via the presence channel. Must build in a console to detect errors.
